# Capitalize first letter of the variable in the windows batch file

Tags: regex, batch-file, sed

I'm trying to capitalize the first letter of the output from the `%COMPUTERNAME%` variable. I have tried the below code which doesn't work.

```
set host=%COMPUTERNAME%
echo %host% | sed 's/^\(.\)/\1\u\2/g/'
```

The output should be `Beast` rather than `BEAST` or `beast`

Comment: SED is not native to Windows so you should tag your question with SED.

Comment: Try `sed -r 's/^(.)/\U\1/'`  It works for me on Windows, but god knows what version of sed you're running.  (Or in what context your batch file is executing)

Comment: i tried this already however it returns all CAPS but my desired output should be "Beast"

Comment: @iab. - Get a new version of `sed`.  Or use `perl`  ( `perl -pe 's/^(.)/\U\1/'` ).  What's the output from `sed --version`, btw?

Comment: hmm.. thanks @zzxyz so it is specific to SED version

Comment: sed (GNU sed) 4.4
Packaged by Cygwin (4.4-1)

Comment: @iab. - oh...you got something else going on then.  mine is gnu sed 4.4

Comment: oh god, I'm sorry, I'm dumb...I was testing with a lower-case string.  `sed -r 's/^(.)(.*)/\U\1\L\2'`

Comment: lol. no worries.. it's not working. I get below error
sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unterminated `s' command

Comment: @iab. - my bad add the `/` right before the last `'` . so `\2/'`  That said, you still may have issues specifically related to the batch file, although if `sed` is complaining, that's a good sign, actually.

Comment: @zzxyz that did the job. Thanks so much for your help. and now i want to store the value "Beast" into one variable so that i could use that variable through out my batch script.

Comment: [CamelCase](https://www.dostips.com/DtCodeCmdLib.php#Function.toCamelCase)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ever often tend to wrap a powershell command for this:

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\10\12\SO_52769852.cmd
@Echo off
For /f %%A in ('
  Powershell -NoP -C "$Env:COMPUTERNAME.Substring(0,1).ToUpper()+$Env:COMPUTERNAME.Substring(1).ToLower()"
') do set host=%%A
Echo:%host%
```

Comment: Can you by any chance break down 1) the reason for the (presumably) single-execution loop/the `/f`, and 2) the flags being passed to powershell?  Being able to run `C#` functions on arbitrary data in a batch file is....cool.

Comment: The for /f is only neccessary to process the output of the powershell command and store the value. While powershell inherits the env from cmd, it can't store itself there because on termination it's inherited env is discarded. The parameters for powershell are truncated for brevity `-NoP` is NoProfile to avoid loading a profiles and `-C` is for command.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `SEd`, you could probably do it as a single line using the built-in `Find` command.

```bat
@For /F "Tokens=2 Delims=:" %%A In ('"Find "" ":%ComputerName:~,1%" 2>&1"') Do @Echo %%A%ComputerName:~1%
```

The idea uses a 'quirk' with `find.exe`, which capitalizes the entire filename in its error message, when it cannot locate a file. I expand the `%COMPUTERNAME%` variable, asking for just its first character, `%ComputerName:~,1%`,and precede that with a character which is invalid in a Windows filename, in this case `:`. If we assume a `%COMPUTERNAME%` value of `iab-desktop`, the error message, *(stdOut, `2>`)* from `Find "" ":i"` would be passed to the `Do` portion as, `File not found - :I`. This is the English version string, but that shouldn't matter, because we have asked for the second token delimited by the `:` character, which will be `I`. I then prepend that result, stored in `%%A` to the expanded value of `%COMPUTERNAME%`, this time asking for all characters except for its first, `%ComputerName:~1%`. The resulting string will be the value of `%COMPTERNAME%` with the first character capitalized.

Comment: Upvoting because it works without sed or powershell.  But an explanation would be helpful for those of us not super strong in cmd prompt.

Comment: @pwilcox, I have included some additional body text as a result of your comment.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "f_leter=%COMPUTERNAME:~0,1%"
set "the_rest=%COMPUTERNAME:~1%"

call :UpCase %f_leter% f
call ::LoCase %the_rest% rest

set result=%f%%rest%
echo %result%

exit /b %errorlevel%
endlocal
::http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_convertcase.php
:LoCase
:: Subroutine to convert a variable VALUE to all lower case.
:: The argument for this subroutine is the variable NAME.
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "var=%~1"
FOR %%i IN ("A=a" "B=b" "C=c" "D=d" "E=e" "F=f" "G=g" "H=h" "I=i" "J=j" "K=k" "L=l" "M=m" "N=n" "O=o" "P=p" "Q=q" "R=r" "S=s" "T=t" "U=u" "V=v" "W=w" "X=x" "Y=y" "Z=z") DO (
 SET "var=!var:%%~i!"
)
endlocal&(
    if "%~2" neq "" (
        set "%~2=%var%"
    ) else (
        echo %var%
    ) 
)&GOTO:EOF

:UpCase
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "var=%~1"
:: Subroutine to convert a variable VALUE to all UPPER CASE.
:: The argument for this subroutine is the variable NAME.
FOR %%i IN ("a=A" "b=B" "c=C" "d=D" "e=E" "f=F" "g=G" "h=H" "i=I" "j=J" "k=K" "l=L" "m=M" "n=N" "o=O" "p=P" "q=Q" "r=R" "s=S" "t=T" "u=U" "v=V" "w=W" "x=X" "y=Y" "z=Z") DO (
    SET "var=!var:%%~i!"
)
endlocal&(
    if "%~2" neq "" (
        set "%~2=%var%"
    ) else (
        echo %var%
    ) 
)&GOTO:EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the `sed` answer, although I'd recommend @LotPings powershell answer on Windows.  Note that for a typical `%computername%` the more key point of your question is converting all but the first character to lower-case.

```
set host=%COMPUTERNAME%
echo %host% | sed -r 's/^(.)(.*)/\U\1\L\2/'
```

Comment: i tried both and they both worked but for my requirement the one @LotPings posted helped much better. Thank you both.