# Echo pcname in Capital and domain.local in lower into config file

Tags: batch-file, variables, echo, system

with computername being uppercse and dns in lowercase

i found this script somewhere, and need to incorporate it in another that echo's the computername and userdnsdomain into a conf file

could you please help me put everything together...
This is the first script that copies some files around, and installs the service. It does put the FQDN into the conf file, but the computername and the domain.local is in capital letters

```
@echo off
@cls

:: Create & Copy necessary directories/files
mkdir "C:\ProgramData\##"
mkdir "C:\ProgramData\##\##.conf.d"
mkdir "C:\ProgramData\##\dev"
copy ##.conf.d "C:\ProgramData\##\##.conf.d"
copy ##_*.exe "C:\ProgramData\##"
copy ##.win.conf "C:\ProgramData\##"
copy dev "C:\ProgramData\##\dev"

:: Function to make domain.local in lowercase
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET dom=%USERDNSDOMAIN%
CALL :LoCase dom
::ECHO %dom%
ENDLOCAL
GOTO:EOF

:LoCase
:: Subroutine to convert a variable VALUE to all lower case.
:: The argument for this subroutine is the variable NAME.
SET %~1=!%1:A=a!
SET %~1=!%1:B=b!
SET %~1=!%1:C=c!
SET %~1=!%1:D=d!
SET %~1=!%1:E=e!
SET %~1=!%1:F=f!
SET %~1=!%1:G=g!
SET %~1=!%1:H=h!
SET %~1=!%1:I=i!
SET %~1=!%1:J=j!
SET %~1=!%1:K=k!
SET %~1=!%1:L=l!
SET %~1=!%1:M=m!
SET %~1=!%1:N=n!
SET %~1=!%1:O=o!
SET %~1=!%1:P=p!
SET %~1=!%1:Q=q!
SET %~1=!%1:R=r!
SET %~1=!%1:S=s!
SET %~1=!%1:T=t!
SET %~1=!%1:U=u!
SET %~1=!%1:V=v!
SET %~1=!%1:W=w!
SET %~1=!%1:X=x!
SET %~1=!%1:Y=y!
SET %~1=!%1:Z=z!
GOTO:EOF

:: Edit hostname in conf file
echo Hostname=%COMPUTERNAME%.%dom% >> "C:\ProgramData\##\##.win.conf"

:: Installing agent using specific config file
cd "\ProgramData\##"
##.exe --config ##.win.conf --install

:: Start ## service
net start "##"
```

Comment: I suggest to invoke powershell as a tool for this, see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52779348/6811411)

Comment: `:LoCase` and `for %%a in (a b c ... x y z) do set "%~1=!%~1:%%a=%%a!"` and `goto :EOF`